# Correctly use of Promises and await/async functions

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, nestjs, promise.all

I'm working in a Backend For Frontend (BFF) that receive a request by front end, the bff request an another api and with responses, creates the object to return to front end.

I would like to know if i'm using promises and await call correctly, there are two situations:

```
const [affiliates, { content }]: [
  { content: AffiliateType[] },
  IManagerTypeList,
] = await Promise.all([
  await this.affiliatesService.getAffiliates(
    { clientId: client?.id },
  ),
  await this.managersService.getManagers(
    { clientId: client?.id },
  ),
])
```

`getAffiliates` and `getManagers` are async methods that call another api. The `content` const i return directly to front end. With `affiliates`, i do the follow:

```
const unresolvedTransformedAffiliateToReturn = affiliates.content.map(
  async (affiliate): Promise<AffiliateType> => {
    const addressInfo: AddressType =
      await this.addressService.getAddressesById(
        affiliate.addressId,
      )

    const managerInfo: ManagersType =
      await this.managersService.getManagers(
        affiliate.managerId,
      )

    return {
      id: affiliate.id,
      name: affiliate.name,
      clientId: affiliate.clientId,
      managerId: affiliate.managerId,
      addressId: affiliate.addressId,
      address: addressInfo,
      manager: managerInfo,
    }
  },
)

const transformedAffiliateToReturn = await Promise.all(
  unresolvedTransformedAffiliateToReturn,
)
```

What is going here. affiliates.content is a array of object. I need to use some variables of affiliate to call `getAddressesById` and `getManagers` endpoints (also asyncs), like addressInfo and managerInfo, then, use this return to return to front end.

The final return to front end is:

```
{
  managers: content,
  affiliates: transformedAffiliateToReturn,
}
```

All works correctly. I'm only wondering if it's the right way to use promise.all and async/wait functions.

Some opinions or suggestions will be appreciate. Thanks!

EDIT:
Example of `getAffiliates` request:

```
getAffiliates<R>(id: number, api?: string): Promise<R> {
  return this.customHttpService.mountRequest(
    RequestTypeEnum.GET,
    `/endpoint/${id}`,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    api,
    true,
)
```

}

`mountRequest` scope:

```
async mountRequest<P, B, H, R>(
  requestType: RequestTypeEnum,
  endpoint: string,
  params?: P,
  body?: B,
  headers?: H,
  api?: string,
  ignoreNotFoundError?: boolean,
  ): Promise<R> {
    const defaultApi: string = api ? api : 
    let request: Observable<AxiosResponse<R>>
    ...
  }
)
```

Comment: you can learn about `async/await` here: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: You don't need to await in a `Promise.all(...)`. The results would automatically be resolved. Instead of awaiting in parallel, you actually made it run in series because you await it like that

Comment: If i don't await in Promise.all, i got this typescript error.

Type 'Promise<AffiliateType[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'AffiliateType[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.

Comment: or if a use ```unresolvedTransformedAffiliateToReturn``` instead of ```transformedAffiliateToReturn``` directly in return, i got this: Type 'Promise<AffiliateType>[]' is not assignable to type 'AffiliateType[]'.
  Type 'Promise<AffiliateType>' is missing the following properties from type 'AffiliateType': id, name, managerId, address, addressId

Comment: Looks like `getAffiliates` and `getManager` return a Promise of Promise. You can definitely refactor that

Comment: Could be. added examples of ```getAffiliates``` in main question. This piece of code was in project when i started.